# Prohibit exporting or sharing documents in UIDocumentBrowserViewController

Tags: ios, uidocumentbrowservc, fileprovider-extension

Is there any way to prohibit exporting files in my `UIDocumentBrowserViewController`-based application that also provides a `FileProvider`?

- The user should only be allowed to view and edit files in the app.
- The user should be able to move files around within the `FileProvider` resource, add new folders, ...

Context:

- I'm building an enterprise app that grants access to a network file system with sensitive information.
- I'm using a `FileProvider` extension that only can be used inside my app.
- I thought of achieving this via the `FPUIActionExtensionViewController` by throwing authentication errors if the `FileProvider` is being accessed from other apps.
- I want to avoid building my own UI and use the one that Apple provides for free.

Answer (score 0):

No, not really. Neither would it make sense to have such a control since taking a screenshot is trivial, and even if you could disable that, taking a photo of the screen is still possible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is built-in. Make your app a managed enterprise app ; then you can control access to the files with configuration profiles.

Comment: Thanks to your tip I found this document: [Managing Devices &  Corporate Data on iOS](https://www.apple.com/business/resources/docs/Managing_Devices_and_Corporate_Data_on_iOS.pdf). Are you talking about the ability to control the Open-In menu?
I think that's exactly what I need. If you get a little more detailed in your answer I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: Yes, Managed Open In was exactly what I was referring to. But I've never done this myself so I can't add any specifics. I just know this is what you're looking for ;)